# Cannot set a ID attribute to a created DOM element in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm trying to set a ID to a element that was created with JavaScript. However, when I run the code I just get the following error message:

> Uncaught TypeError: dwarfButton.setAttribute is not a function

I did research around here and it pretty much says that if I want to add a ID attribute to one of my created elements, I have to use `setAttribute("id", "whatever-else-here")`, but instead I get a error message stating that it's not a function?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    game.start();
});

var 
game = {
    start: function() {
        logMessage("Welcome to the Arena!");
        logMessage("Select your Fighter.");
        var dwarfButton = chatbox.appendChild(document.createElement("button")).textContent = "DWARF";
        dwarfButton.setAttribute("id", "dwarf");
    },
```

Comment: dwarfButton is a text, not a element. Put the document.createElement("button") to a variable and assign id to it.

Comment: Where is your chatbox object?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're problem is on these lines:

```
var dwarfButton = chatbox.appendChild(document.createElement("button")).textContent = "DWARF";
dwarfButton.setAttribute("id", "dwarf");
```

You have a bit of chaining here, but ultimately you are setting the `dwarfButton` variable to the string `"DWARF"`, rather then the DOM element you created.

Try this instead:

```
var dwarfButton = document.createElement("button");
dwarfButton.textContent = "DWARF";
dwarfButton.setAttribute("id", "dwarf");
chatbox.appendChild(dwarfButton);
```

Comment: Thank you, this solved the issue. Also I went ahead and created a function called "createButton" so I wouldn't have to write all that per button I wanted created. Thank you so much mate :)